# Multiple selections with ListBox?

Tags: c#, listbox

I've decided to use a `ListBox` for my application, in this case, charitably named `lb`. I went on to fill it with content (only a handful of `string`s) and manipulated it's size and appearance before smacking it into my form.

Among the options I played with, I touched on `lb.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple;`, because I wanted the user to be able to select one or more of my `string`s.

Now, up until the point where I added the `SelectionMode` line, `lb.SelectedIndex` would always point me to the user's selection of choice (after it had been made, obviously).

But it doesn't seem to do so when multiple items are selected. It only seems to point to the "first" selected `string`.

Is there some way I can tell it to go to the NEXT selected item, or perhaps get a new list with the index of all the selected items?

How can I best go about getting all the selected strings my user chose?

Comment: What is `ListBox` from?  ASP, WinForms, WPF, Windows App?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a plural version of the `SelectedIndex`property, called [`SelectedIndices`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindices(v=vs.110).aspx). That is probably what your are looking for.

Also check the [`SelectedItems`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems(v=vs.110).aspx) property, which may in fact be closer to what you actually want.

The above is true for Windows Forms application. If you are making a WPF application, [`SelectedItems`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selecteditems(v=vs.110).aspx) is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Theres `ListBox.SelectedIndices` that returns a `ListBox.SelectedIndexCollection`, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.SelectedIndices%29;) for reference and example.

Comment: Good answer, +1. I went with the one posted by Fredrik. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

For getting collection of selected objects use property SelectedItems.